# Maximum number of vectors with $\mathbf{a_i} \cdot \mathbf{a_j} < 0$

Tags: vectors

Find the maximal $k$ such that there exist vectors $\mathbf{a_1},...,\mathbf{a_k}$ with the property that $\mathbf{a_i} \cdot \mathbf{a_j} < 0$ for all $1 \leq i < j \leq k$ if all vectors are from $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Attempt:

$\mathbf{a_i} \cdot \mathbf{a_j} < 0$ implies that the angle between each vector must be greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I realize that $k=3$ and $k=4$ for $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{R^3}$ respectively. Thus I conjecture that $k=n+1$ for $\mathbb{R^n}$.

But how do I know if this is true?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: source of the problem?

Comment: by the way, it's true.

Comment: My teacher found it somewhere.